# how to access .net web method via SOAP in php

Tags: php, .net, soap, nusoap

when access function in .NET it will return null always

```
//PHP
$client = new nusoap_client("http://14.14.9.4:82/medApi.asmx?wsdl",true);
$result = $client->call("AddDepartment", array('test'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);


//.NET Coading
[WebMethod]
public string AddDepartment(string Param1) {
    if(Param1 == null)
        return "value is null";
    } else {
       return "value present";
    }
}
```

It returns always

> array(AddDepartmentResult->value is null)

Comment: What does the WSDL for the `AddDepartment` call look like?